# Error in ArrayAdapter Generic

Tags: java, android

this is what i see in the error line  
-Multiple markers at this line  
- ArrayAdapter is a raw type.  
 
-References to generic type ArrayAdapter should be parameterized  
- The constructor ArrayAdapter(RetrieveActivity.MyAsyncTask, int, ArrayList) is 
     undefined  
may i know what is wrong with my code. I wanna display arraylist into the listview. but i can't make it due to the error. tq

```
package com.example.m2mai;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;
import java.sql.Timestamp;
import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Date;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Toast;


public class RetrieveActivity extends Activity {
    ArrayAdapter mArrayAdapter;
    ArrayList mNameList = new ArrayList();
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_retrieve);
    }



    public void getStream(View v)
    {   
        new MyAsyncTask().execute();
    }

private class MyAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String>
{
    public ArrayList<String> atList=new ArrayList<String>();
    public ArrayList<String> dataList=new ArrayList<String>();


        protected String doInBackground(String... params) 
        {
            return getData();

        }
        public long getDateTo() 
      {
        EditText toText = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.dateTo);
        String To = toText.getText().toString();

        DateFormat dateFormatTo = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
        Date dateTo = null;
        try {
            dateTo = dateFormatTo.parse(To);
        } catch (java.text.ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        long timeTo = dateTo.getTime();
        new Timestamp(timeTo);  
        return timeTo/1000;
      }

        protected String getData()
        {
            String toTS = ""+getDateTo();
            String decodedString="";
            String returnMsg="";
            String request = "http://api.carriots.com/devices/defaultDevice@eric3231559.eric3231559/streams/?order=-1&max=5&at_to="+toTS;
            URL url;
            HttpURLConnection connection = null;  
            try {
                url = new URL(request); 
                connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                //establish the parameters for the http post request
                connection.addRequestProperty("carriots.apikey", "====================");
                connection.addRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");
                connection.setRequestMethod("GET"); 
                //create a buffered reader to interpret the incoming message from the carriots system
                BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream()));
                while ((decodedString = in.readLine()) != null) 
                {
                    returnMsg+=decodedString;
                }
                in.close();
                connection.disconnect();
                JSONObject nodeRoot = new JSONObject(returnMsg); 
                JSONArray res = nodeRoot.getJSONArray("result");

                 for (int i = 0; i < res.length(); i++) 
                    {
                    JSONObject childJSON = res.getJSONObject(i);
                    if (childJSON.get("data")!=null)
                        {
                       String value = childJSON.getString("data");
                       dataList.add(value);
                       JSONObject node=new JSONObject(value);
                       atList.add(node.get("temperature").toString()); 
                        }
                    } 
                 }
                 catch (Exception e) 
            {
                e.printStackTrace(); 
                returnMsg=""+e;
            }
            //Log.d("returnMsg",returnMsg.toString());
            return returnMsg;
        }

        protected void onPostExecute(String result)
            {

//          int a = atList.size();
//          String b = ""+a;
//          Log.d("atList",b);
            for(int i = 0; i < atList.size(); i++)
            {
            ListView mainListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);

            // Create an ArrayAdapter for the ListView
            mArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,mNameList); //<---- error here

            // Set the ListView to use the ArrayAdapter
            mainListView.setAdapter(mArrayAdapter);

            mNameList.add(atList.get(i).toString());
            mArrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),result, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            EditText myData1=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);
            myData1.setText(atList.get(0));

            }
    }

}
```

Comment: Change `this` to `RetrieveActivity.this` in `mArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,mNameList);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Also specify the specify the parameters for the type of array adapter to remove warnings like this

```
ArrayAdapter<String>  mArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(RetrieveActivity.this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,mNameList);
```

Also change the definition of arraylist to

```
ArrayList<String> mNameList = new ArrayList<String>();
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help... it solve my problem. but may i know what does the list keep extending when i press retrieve again? am  i able to renew the list ?

Comment: Tq i found a way to do that. i move the arraylist declaration to the asyntask area . tq

Comment: `List<String> mNameList = new ArrayList<String>();` is better practice

Comment: anyone know that how can i avoid it "crash" ? for example like i didn't fill in my date this program will crash

Answer (score 2):

> ArrayAdapter is a raw type.

it is expecting that you provide the type of object the adapter is going to handle. For instance,

```
 ArrayAdapter<String> mAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(...
```

> The constructor ArrayAdapter(RetrieveActivity.MyAsyncTask, int,
>   ArrayList)

The first argument of the constructor is a `Context` object and not an instance of your AsyncTask (which this is referring to, in your case)

```
ArrayAdapter<String> mAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(NameOfYoutActivity.this, ...
```

In `onPostExecute` you are creating multiple instance of your Adapter. I do think that is not useful

```
@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String result) {

        ListView mainListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);
        mArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapterString> (NameOfYoutActivity.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,mNameList);

        for(int i = 0; i < atList.size(); i++)  { 
             mArrayAdapter.add(atList.get(i).toString());                  
        }
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),result, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        EditText myData1=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);
        myData1.setText(atList.get(0));

}
```

Comment: tq so much, it helps a lot. multiple instance of my adapter ? what does that means ? sorry i am kinda new and noob in android.

Answer (score 0):

```
// "this" is not application context.
mArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, mNameList);
```

You can create UI in `onCreate()` method and use `mArrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();` for update.